# How Do I Parse A Datetime String With The Typer Library?

Tags: python, typer

If I have a function that says

```
from datetime import datetime

import typer

TODAYS_DATE = datetime.now()

def main(
        s3_bucket: str,
        target_date: Optional[str] = TODAYS_DATE.isoformat(),
        region: str = "us-east-1"):
      """
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    typer.run(main)
```

How can I avoid having to cast the datetime to a string?

Answer (score 0):

The typer documentation doesn't state this but it turns out the library is smart enough that you can declare

```
from datetime import datetime

import typer

TODAYS_DATE = datetime.now()

def main(
        s3_bucket: str,
        target_date: Optional[datetime] = TODAYS_DATE.isoformat(),
        region: str = "us-east-1"):
      """
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    typer.run(main)
```

And it results in a CLI option like

```
Options:
  --target-date [%Y-%m-%d|%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S|%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]
                                  [default: 2021-11-10 13:29:43.349936]
```

automatically.